# Change specific character color in Tkinter.Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I'm trying to change specific characters color in Tkinter.Canvas... I search on net for a solution and nothing.

```
txt1 = canvasFrame.create_text(500,100, text = "redblue", font = "Calibri, 30", fill = "#4587de")
```

The actual color is blue, I need to paint the 'red string' with red color and the 'blue string' still blue.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: split the text, give different colors and then join them perhaps?

Comment: @MohitChandak How to do this?

Comment: Trying running same line, txt1 for text "red" and txt2 line for "blue", fill in with required colors and then do txt3=txt1+txt2

Comment: @MohitChandak its impossible, txt1 is a object not a string

Comment: @MohitChandak: text colors don't work that way. You can't add two strings like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas doesn't allow to use multiple colors for one string object. You will need to use two `create_text` commands, one for each color. That also means you'll have to calculate the proper spacing and alignment of the two strings on the canvas so that it looks like one string.

The canvas isn't a very good solution if you need to color individual characters. If you can, you might want to switch to using a text widget.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to make a blue text object `redblue` and then put a red text_object `red` on top of it?  I haven't tried it, but it seems like it ought to work.  Of course, a text widget is better if it suits the OP's needs, and this hack wouldn't work for "redgreenblue".

Comment: @saulspatz: yes, that would work, though you would have to compute the exact pixel location of the overlayed text.

Answer (score 0):

One can put a text widget (with colored text) on a canvas.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
text = Text(canvas, height=1, width=20)
text.insert('end', 'red green blue')
text['state'] = DISABLED  # read only
canvas.create_window(100, 20, anchor='nw', window=text)
root.mainloop()
```

There are other SO answers on coloring slices within a text by using tags.